# What happens if I unsubscribe from Apple Music, then resubscribe at a later date?

Tags: music

I want to cancel my apple music subscription for now, but may want to bring it back this summer. Will all the music I added be permanently removed when I unsubscribe, or will re-subscribing retrieve all my previous music?

Answer (score 5):

When you unsubscribe from Apple Music, all your playlists, downloaded songs/videos will be removed from your devices. If you want to resubscribe at a later date, then you have to start from scratch. You have to find songs, create playlists and so on.